# Easiest way to install a real door in this doorway

Tags: bathroom, doors

Into our bathroom we have this accordion style door. The opening is exactly 24 inches wide and 80 inches high as it is now. Is there a way to install a door without taking off all the trim and everything or what would be the easiest recommended route?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Is there a way?" - certainly yes. Will it look good & work well? Probably not...

Comment: The exact frame measurements might mean a 24x80 inch door will need a shave/trim(cut).  Most doors just need the hinges and latch made into the frame.  Put some door jambs/stops on and you should have a hinged door.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You can purchase 24" door slabs (which are undersized for your opening), and you can purchase hinges and stops. What's the problem you're facing? Please revise to be more specific.

Comment: "Chesterton's Fence" frame challenge: Why is an accordion door there now? Maybe there was a good reason the original door was swapped out. Will a new regular door cover something? Or not open fully, due to floor un-level-ness?

Answer (score 3):

It appears exceedingly likely that there was a normal door here before, so one can be there again.

Installing hinges and a door is a bit more skill required than installing a pre-hung door, which is why pre-hung doors are common, but it certainly can be done, whether you tackle the job or hire a **competent** finish carpenter to do it. *Which is the "easiest way" you asked about, **if** you can find said "competent finish carpenter."*

The things you'll need to pay attention to if DIY-ing the door install are alignment of the hinges in multiple directions, and shaping of the door to fit the frame and allow it to close. Doors were installed this way for centuries before pre-hung doors came along, so it's quite possible to learn, and you can find books that include the full process via a library.

I expect you'll find signs of the old hinges when you remove the accordion door.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell exactly, but it looks as if there is a regular door frame there. It is covered in sloppy caulk that will have to be removed.

*The following is assuming the door frame opening is square and plumb.*

A standard 24 inch door, should fit. These can be purchased at most any home center.  You only need a hollow core interior slab door. get one that is "Bored". (pre-drilled for the latch and knob)  You will also need door stop molding. Enough to fit to both sides and across the top.

It can be done, but will require lots of patience and diligent work.  You will need tools such as a drill, 7/8' spade bit  a Circular saw, a straight edge at least 7 feet, clamps and an extra person to help.

You can buy a door hinge mortising kit, [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WPWM7K9) , but will also need a router.
Or

You can try to used flat non mortise hinges such as [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08ZC58R7C)
3 will hold up a hollow core door nicely.

If the fit with the non mortise hinges is tight you will need to trim a little,  ( maybe 1/8 inch) from the hinge side of the door. (This is where the circular saw, straight edge and clamps come in. )
But easier than buying all the other tools.

Trimming the door will also allow the striker for the latch to fit without mortising.

Get the door hung.

install the latch and knob.

Measure and mark where the striker plate goes.

drill the 7/8 hole, About 3/4 inch deep in the frame for the opening in the striker plate. Attach the striker plate.

Close the door. Make adjustment as necessary.

Measure and cut the door stop trim to fit the outside frame of the door.

Attach the stop trim with finish nails just about 1/32 inch from the outside face of the door. ( you can use a credit card as a spacer.)

Caulk the trim and do your painting when the caulk is dry.

You have a door.